# In C++-17, how to detect the existence of a templated static member function at compile time

Tags: c++, c++17

I have a templated function (`Process`) where I would like to perform a compile time check to see if the supplied typename (`Z`) has a templated static member function taking arguments of the two supplied types (`X`) and (`Y`).

Is it possible to do this with an `if constexpr` test and if so, what would it be?

```
#include <iostream>

struct A { template<typename X, typename Y> static bool compare(const X&, const Y&) { return true; } };
struct B { };

template <typename Z, typename X, typename Y>
inline void Process(X x, Y y)
{    
    if constexpr (std::is_invocable_v<decltype(Z::compare), const X&, const Y&> )
    {
        Z::compare(x,y);
    }
    else { 
        std::cout << "hi";
    }
}

int main()
{
    Process<A>(3,2);
    Process<B>(3,2);    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't think of a way to do it with `if constexpr` alone, without a pair of overloads to test with SFINAE. See if something like this works for you:

```
template <typename Z, typename X, typename Y>
auto test(X x, Y y) ->
    std::enable_if_t<sizeof(decltype(Z::compare(x, y))*) != 0, std::true_type>;

template <typename Z>
std::false_type test(...);

template <typename Z, typename X, typename Y>
inline void Process(X x, Y y)
{    
    if constexpr (decltype(test<Z>(x, y))::value)
    {
        Z::compare(x,y);
    }
    else { 
        std::cout << "hi";
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/ozdsjo).

This doesn't test that `Z` has a templated member function specifically, just that it has a static member function with the right name callable with the right arguments.